# Elementwise multiplication of numpy matrix and column array

Tags: python, numpy

Using numpy, I want to multiple a matrix `x` by a column array `y`, elementwise:

```
   x = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
   y = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
   z = numpy.multiply(x, y)
   print z
```

This gives the output as if `y` is a row array:

```
   [[ 1  4  9]
    [ 4 10 18]
    [ 7 16 27]]
```

However, I want the output as if `y` is a column array:

```
   [[ 1  2  3]
    [ 8 10 12]
    [21 24 27]]
```

So how can I manipulate `y` to achieve this? If I use:

```
y = numpy.transpose(y)
```

then `y` remains the same shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose it in another list to make it 2D:

```
>>> y2 = numpy.transpose([y])
>>> y2
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> numpy.multiply(x, y2)
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [21, 24, 27]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't transpose `y` is because it's initialized as a 1-D array. Transposing an array only makes sense in two (or more) dimensions.

To get around these mixed-dimension issues, `numpy` actually provides a set of convenience functions to sanitize your inputs:

```
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y1 = np.atleast_1d(y)  # Converts array to 1-D if less than that
y2 = np.atleast_2d(y)  # Converts array to 2-D if less than that
y3 = np.atleast_3d(y)  # Converts array to 3-D if less than that
```

I also think `np.column_stack` falls under this convenience category, as it puts together 1-D and 2-D arrays as columns like you would expect, rather than having to figure out the right series of reshapes and stacks.

```
y1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y2 = np.array([2, 4, 6])
y3 = np.array([[2, 6], [2, 4], [7, 7]])
y = np.column_stack((y1, y2, y3))
```

I think these functions aren't as well known as they should be, and I find them much easier, more flexible, and safer than manually fiddling with reshape or array dimensions. They also avoid making copies when possible, which can be a small performance speedup.

---

To answer your question, you should use `np.atleast_2d` to convert your array to a 2-D array, then transpose it.

```
y = np.atleast_2d(y).T
```

The other way to quickly do it without worrying about `y` is to transpose `x` then transpose the result back.

```
z = (x.T * y).T
```

Though this can obfuscate the intent of the code. It is probably faster though if performance is important.

---

If performance is important, that can inform which method you want to use. Some timings on my computer:

```
%timeit x * np.atleast_2d(y).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.98 us per loop

%timeit (x.T*y).T
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.27 us per loop

%timeit x * np.transpose([y])
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.2 us per loop

%timeit x * y.reshape(-1, 1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.66 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reshape`:

```
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The y variable has a shape of (3,).  If you construct it this way:

y = numpy.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2)

...it will have a shape of (1,3), which you can transpose to get the result you want:

y = numpy.array([1, 2, 3], ndmin=2).T
z = numpy.multiply(x, y)